# Fill textboxes based upon current Dropdownlist (database items) selection (asp.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a dropdown box in my view which is populated with objects from database. Now what I want to do is, based upon selection in the Dropdown fill various textboxes with property values of the object selected in the dropdownlist.

There are numerous examples where you *copy the selected dropdown value* in the textbox using JQuery / JavaScript etc, but I can't find any doing the same but instead of copying; place the values of the *properties of the object* in the textboxes.

How would this be done in a nice way? I would prefer to do it without posting the entire form, though those answers may be posted also.

Comment: You don't select *an object* from a dropdown box but a single string value (or multiple values if enabled). That's the reason why all the examples you've seen simply copy the selected value in a textbox. So where is this object coming from given a selected value?

Comment: I know that, i do already use dropdown boxes but I wanted to show that I was interested in the object behind the selection in the dropbox, so not the ID / name / whatever the dropbox selects (the value is the id) but the object in the DB behind the ID whit value selected in the dropbox. I need the DB information not the value the dropbox gives me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('select#yourControlId').change(function () {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();

    document.location = '<%= Url.Action( "Action", "Controller") %>' + '?val=' + selectedVal;
 });
```

Then you'll capture `val` in the signature of teh action method and populate the appropriate textboxes...

***Or***

You could also on `Changed` do a JQuery Ajax post...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/